# c++ how to free a static reference to an outside object?

Tags: c++, c++11, static-members

First you need to look into this code, here I have two classes -- one is the `TreasureBag` and the other is the `Sprite`. I have multiple copies of sprite but there is only one bag (hence it's `static`). The sprites acquire the bag and collect treasures, store inside it, then the next sprite comes and use it for treasure collection.

Here is my code --

```
class TreasureBag {
    private:
        int* bag ; int size ; int index ;

    public:
        TreasureBag(int size = 10) {
            this->index = 0 ; this->size = size ;
            this->bag = new int[this->size] ;
        }
        ~TreasureBag() { delete [] this->bag ; }
        void put(int data) { this->bag[this->index++] = data ;}
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &os, const TreasureBag &tb);
};

class Sprite 
{
    private:
        static TreasureBag tbag ; int points = 0 ; string name ;

    public:
        Sprite(string name) { this->name = name ; }
        ~Sprite() { ; } // --> not sure what to do here
        void collect(int data) { this->tbag.put(data); }
        void acquireTreasureBag(TreasureBag &tb) { Sprite::tbag = tb ; }
        void releaseTreasureBag() { ; } // ---> not sure what to do here either
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Sprite &s);
};
TreasureBag Sprite::tbag ;
```

Inside the main, I have two sprites s1 and s2, and one treasure bag. The sprite s1 comes first, grabs it and put stuffs inside, then it `releases` the bag and s2 acquires it.

```
int main()
{
    TreasureBag tb(5) ; Sprite s1("s1");
    s1.acquireTreasureBag(tb); // <-- Looks like this line is problematic

    /*s1.collect(1); s1.collect(2);
    cout << s1 << endl ;
    s1.releaseTreasureBag();

    Sprite s2("s2"); s2.acquireTreasureBag(tb);
    s2.collect(3);
    cout << s2 << endl ;*/
    return 0 ;
}
```

But when I run the code (please see the un-commented lines), I get this error --

```
*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000002495040 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What is the best way to handle this kind of situation? Is my design principle ok? Moreover, I am not sure what I should do in the sprite destructor `~Sprite()` and the `releaseTreasureBag()` procedure.

please help.

Comment: Which line is the error happening on? You don't need to do anything in the destructor, because `tbag` isn't a pointer. It's a copy of the `TreasureBag` that was acquired.

Comment: This use of `static` makes no sense, especially when you are using it with `this->`.

Comment: yes, `this->` is gone.

Comment: @Barmar that's right.

Comment: Your copy-assignment operator fails to perform a deep copy on the resource, so on the line `Sprite::tbag = tb` you now have two pointers to the same `bag` which is deleted twice by the destructors of the two instances. Please read [What is The Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: Implementation details aside, there are serious design problems with this code. You seem to want `TreasureBag` to be a singleton, yet you construct two instances of it. You seem to want one sprite to have exclusive ownership of the bag at a time, yet the one of the `TreasureBag` instances is shared across all sprites at all times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't respect rule of three (or Five).
Use `std::vector` to avoid to manage memory yourself:

```
class TreasureBag {
private:
    std::vector<int> bag;
    int max_size;

public:
    TreasureBag(int size = 10) : max_size(size) {}
    void put(int data) { if (bag.size() < max_size) bag.push_back(data) ;}
public:
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &os, const TreasureBag &tb);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might want to use smart pointers for this:

```
class Sprite {
    static std::shared_ptr<TreasureBag> tbag;

public:
    void acquire(std::shared_ptr<TreasureBag> tb) {
        tbag = tb;
    }

    void release() {
        tbag.reset();
    }
};
```

And then construct your `TreasureBag` as a `shared_ptr` too:

```
std::shared_ptr<TreasureBag> tb = std::make_shared<TreasureBag>(5);
Sprite s1("s1");
s1.acquire(tb);
```

Comment: thanks, but how should I call to the member function of `TreasureBag` over the `shared_ptr` ?

Comment: what I mean what should I do to call `tb.put()` ??

Comment: @ramgorur `tb->put()`.